# EMTYFILE flag location

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

During execution of a `DBCC SHRINKFILE ('file_name' , EMPTYFILE)` command is there any kind of flag in a DMV, DBCC or other monitoring tool that reflects that no data should be written to 'file_name'?

Comment: Have a look at the results from [`sp_lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-lock-transact-sql). I also tripped over [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/31554/how-to-check-progress-of-dbcc-shrinkfile) whilst searching.

Comment: @HABO Thank you! `sp_lock` **does** show an exclusive lock on a file during execution of `DBCC SHRINKFILE ('file_name' , EMPTYFILE)` I am also wondering how sql server knows that nothing should be written to 'file_name' after a successful execution of this command.

Comment: What `state` is reported for the file by [`sys.master_files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql) before and after the shrinkage?

Comment: @HABO `state` is `0` before and after shrinkage.